# Powerpoint hyperlink regions

Tags: image, powerpoint, transparent

I want to make regions of a powerpoint clickable. Think of a map of a country where you want users to be able to click on each state. I've tried placing a clickable transparent image over each state, but the image is only transparent when the presentation is not running. As soon as the presentation runs, the image goes from transparent to white, thus covering the state. Anyone know how to keep the image transparent while the presentation is running, or a better way altogether?

Thanks in advance.

I should have mentioned that I need some code to fire so I had to use an ActiveX control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assign a Run Macro action setting to each autoshape. Have it run something like this:

```
Sub DoSomething(oSh as Shape)
  ' You now have a reference to the clicked shape:
   MsgBox oSh.Name
   ' Now what do you want it to do when clicked?
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Using an AutoShape with No Fill for the color on No Line for the Line Color has worked for me in the past.  Here's a [quick tutorial](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/msoffice/how-to-disguise-hyperlinks-in-powerpoint/132).

Comment: I should have mentioned that I need some code to fire so I had to use an ActiveX control.